# Process and plot the supposed data

Tags: graphing-functions

### **Build a Plot**

Suppose it's given us experimental data is the array of pairs:

first number L = PO2 - *partial pressure*

and second Y = SatHb - *Oxygen saturation*

The Array is **NOT** monotonic

We need to processing the experimental data:

1. Building Hill plot [x, y] by redefining axis:

```
    float32  x,y;
    x=log(L);  
    y=log(Y/(100-Y))/100; # Y represented like percentage value 0..100
```

2. Linear transformation of both axis:  Specifically vertical (Y) shift
   till the data are extrapolating to zero And therefore [x.y] is
   straight line for x<1.
3. Fitting 2 parts of the data points in Hill plot [x.y] with 3 lines
   (Green, Red, Blue) Boundaries are adjustable with 2 double sliders
   and rarely changed once set. Slopes of the lines are shown and
   reported Intercept of the left (green) line should be close to zero,
   slope should be close to 1. Blue line is built automatically: slope
   is the same as green, intercept is the intercept of green plus 1.
   If data are good data should asymptotically go to blue line
4. All 3 lines drawn on the original [L, Y] plot according to reverse
   Hill transformation:

```
float32 Y, L, T;  
L=pow(10, x); 
T=pow(10, y);
Y=1/((1/T)+1);
```

5. Threshold are calculated for 20, 50 80% of the SatHb  Namely at what
   PO2 the SatHb is 20, 50 and 80 %. For this purpose use a polynomial
   fit of 7th order then function "threshold" to find the corresponding
   fractional indexes for the Y array.  Then Interpolation of the
   polynomial fit to find 3 corresponding L values

(3 corresponding L values reported to be output)

> I need to code this but i`d would like to know at first how it looks
> like or be more explained

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't know how plot exactly will look like, but it`s similar to this [link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/core/lw/2.0/html/tileshop_pmc/tileshop_pmc_inline.html?title=Click%20on%20image%20to%20zoom&p=PMC3&id=4666443_EDU-0014-2015.01.jpg)